# Leave column out of Oracle insert statement

Tags: oracle

I have an insert statement that I am trying to run against an Oracle database. The insert statement is very simple, and I only want to insert a value into one column. The table itself has more than one column, but I am only interested in filling one of the columns with data. The format of my query is similar to the one below:

```
insert into myTable (col1) Values (val1)
```

However, this throws the following error:

```
ORA-00904: "col1": invalid identifier
```

I've checked to make sure that the column is named correctly, and my only other thought is that something is wrong with my syntax. There are no constraints on the table such as primary keys. Is it possible to only insert values into certain columns when executing an insert statement in Oracle?

Comment: You say the column is named correctly, Oracle says it is not. I'm inclined to trust Oracle, in the absence of any proof on your side.

Comment: Is col1 the primary key of your table?

Answer (score 4):

Check that you didn't quote the column name on creation of the table. If you did, the column name is stored as you quoted it. For example:

```
create table table1 (
id number(2)
)
```

has a different column name to this

```
create table table2 (
"id" number(2)
)
```

Oracle by default stores the (unquoted) column names in uppercase. Quoted are stored as is.

You can use a `DESC table_name` to see how the columns are stored.

The following

```
select id from table1
select iD from table1
select ID from table1
```

fetch the records, while only

```
select "id" from table2
```

will fetch records.

```
select id from table2
```

will throw the `ORA-00904 : "ID" : invalid identifier` error.

You may have inadvertently done the quoting during creation while using tools as established below:

https://community.oracle.com/thread/2349926

Btw: Yes it is possible to insert records for only one column, as long as the other columns do not have a `NOT NULL` constraint on them.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I think you may be double quoting the column in the insert statement (not on table creation), although your example is misleading.  I guess this because of your error, which says "col1" is invalid, not "COL1" is invalid.  Consider this simple test:

```
SQL> create table mytable
(
col1 varchar2(10)
)
Table created.
SQL> -- incorrect column name, without double quotes
SQL> insert into mytable(col2) values ('abc')
insert into mytable(col2) values ('abc')
Error at line 9
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 11
ORA-00904: "COL2": invalid identifier
SQL> -- incorrect column name, with double quotes
SQL> insert into mytable("col2") values ('abc')
insert into mytable("col2") values ('abc')
Error at line 12
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 11
ORA-00904: "col2": invalid identifier
SQL> -- correct column name, without double quotes (works)
SQL> insert into mytable(col1) values ('abc')
1 row created.
SQL> -- correct column name, with double quotes (fails)
SQL> insert into mytable("col1") values ('abc')
insert into mytable("col1") values ('abc')
Error at line 18
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 1
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: character string buffer too small
ORA-06512: at line 11
ORA-00904: "col1": invalid identifier
```

The last failed insert attempt is what I think you may be doing:

```
insert into mytable("col1") values ...
```

based on the error message:

```
ORA-00904: "col1": invalid identifier
```

So the solution would simply be remove the double quoting around the column name in the insert.

Comment: I think it's more likely the OP changed the real name in the statement and error message for posting, and lost the case in the process; but this is certainly a possibility worth checking too.

Comment: @AlexPoole You may be correct, Alex, not sure what to believe from the OP ;)

Answer (score 0):

It's most probably a syntax error

```
Desc myTable;
insert into myTable (col1) Values ('val1')
```

Ensure col1 is a valid column in the table, and you're simply not trying to say 'select the left-most column.

edit: Is it possible to only insert values into certain columns when executing an insert statement in Oracle?

Yes if you want to only insert into certain columns then simply specify it

e.g.

```
insert into myTable (col1, col2, col6) Values ('val1', 'val2', 'val3');
```

This will only work if the column itself doesn't have a NOT NULL constraint - in which case it will not allow a value to be enetered (unless again there's a default value).